# Need Use ioreg get USB Serial Number via variables with Python in MacOS?

Tags: python, macos

I try write a small script:

```
import os
os.system("ioreg -p IOUSB -l -b | grep 'USB Serial Number'")
```

result:

```
"USB Serial Number" = "123456789101213131516"
```

i want result only is:

```
123456789101213131516
```

and set it as a variable

I look forward to your support!

Comment: Split using `=` and take the index 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using `ioreg` so used your output as my input.

Check this.

**Code**

```
import os
string='"USB Serial Number" = "123456789101213131516"'
print (string.replace("\"","").split("=")[1])
```

**Output:**

```
123456789101213131516
```

Comment: i will try it, tks

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was helpful, else feel free to ask doubt.

Comment: yeah run ok
i want set it as variable?
print (string.replace("\"","").split("=")[1])

Comment: Yes, you can directly set `os.system` output as varaiable and parse it.